# inserting data in dataframe by lookup

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes

```
a) df1 columns(origin, destination, miles)
b) df2 columns (place, some_value)
```

a place can be both origin and destination. 
I want to insert two more columns in df1; origin_value, destination_value which is equal to some_value from df2 matched to the same place as origin and destination.

so the result would be something like this

```
df1 columns (origin, destination, miles, origin_value, dest_value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='origin', right_on='place').rename(columns = {'value':'origin_value'}).drop('place',1)
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='destination', right_on='place').rename(columns = {'value':'dest_value'}).drop('place',1)
```

Consider this example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'origin': ['a','b', 'c', 'b'],
    'destination': ['b', 'c', 'a', 'a'],
    'miles':[10,20,30,10]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'place': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'value': [2000, 5000, 3000]
})
```

then,

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='origin', right_on='place').rename(columns = {'value':'origin_value'}).drop('place',1)
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='destination', right_on='place').rename(columns = {'value':'dest_value'}).drop('place',1)
```

Output:

```
  origin destination  miles  origin_value  dest_value
0      a           b     10          2000        5000
1      b           c     20          5000        3000
2      c           a     30          3000        2000
3      b           a     10          5000        2000
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `replace`

```
cols = ['origin', 'destination']
m = dict(zip(df2.place, df2.value))
df1.join(df1[cols].replace(m).add_suffix('_value'))

  origin destination  miles  origin_value  destination_value
0      a           b     10          2000               5000
1      b           c     20          5000               3000
2      c           a     30          3000               2000
3      b           a     10          5000               2000
```